# Get folder with path ONEDRIVE

Tags: onedrive

I am using this [PHP API](https://github.com/krizalys/onedrive-php-sdk) and I want to check if folder is created if not then create it. So I am using

```
function folderExists()
    {
        return $this->folder = $this->client->fetchObject("me/skydrive/FOLDER_NAME");
    }
```

But I cannot get the path right. Best I can get is this

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The resource
>   'd3b7bfe6cdaba4b7' doesn't exist.

But that ID is still not enough,  I would need this

> folder.d3b7bfe6cdaba4b7.D3B7BFE6CDABA4B7!527

to access it.

Comment: Not sure if it's an artifact of the SDK you are using or not, but that's using the legacy Live Connect API, which is no longer being maintained. I'd recommend using something that targets the Microsoft Graph: https://graph.microsoft.com.

Comment: Well, looks like I can start over, thanks for recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with this

```
function folderExists()
{
    $id = $this->client->fetchRoot();
    $folders = $id->fetchObjects();
    foreach ($folders as $id => $folder) {
        if($folder->getName() === $this->config['FOLDER_NAME'])
            return $this->folder = $folder;
    }
}
```